# PDF417 barcode in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, barcode

How would you generate PDF417 bar code in wordpress? 
What php library would you use and how would you call it from functions.php?
Is this actally a good start?
This is something I have found:
https://github.com/tecnickcom/tc-lib-pdf

My ideal scenario would be to have outside php library then include it within functions.php file then call it with parameter that is converted to PDF417 image (preferably SVG, but PNG is also ok).

Answer (score 0):

If you can install `Zint` on your server, I have created a PHP class that can generate that format of barcode.

https://github.com/delboy1978uk/php-zint

```
<?php

use Del\Barcode\Service\BarcodeService;

// Use [] instead of () if barcode has parenthesis
$barcodeNumber = '646496874646'; // <- whatever, not the real format

$path = realpath('/path/to/genration/folder'); // Where zint will dump the image (gets deleted after generation)
$barcodeService = new BarcodeService($path);

$image = $barcodeService->generate(
    BarcodeService::TYPE_PDF_417,
    $barcodeNumber
);

echo $image;
```

Comment: What kind of output does it give? And jow jeavy is zint for the server itself?

Comment: zint is very fast as it is a native linux command. The image can be rendered as either a Portable Network Graphic (PNG) image, as Encapsulated Post Script (EPS)(read that as PDF compatible) or as a Scalable Vector Graphic (SVG).

Comment: You can find the manual here https://zint.github.io/ Although it's easier just calling my code, however my code has only been written to output PNG for the time being. (feel free to refactor and send a pull request though! ;-) )

Comment: Can it output directly to php variable instead of file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172418/discussion-between-wed-and-delboy1978uk).

Comment: Have you ever considered this?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to run Zint with shell_exec() and directly output data of barcode image to PHP. Zint has to be installed on server.

```
<?php 

$bcinput = "This is test";

$output = shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/zint -b 55 --border=5 --direct -d "' . $bcinput .'"');

echo "<img src='data:image/gif;base64," . base64_encode($output) . "'/>";
```